# sorting queue per time

Tags: c#, queue

I have an object queue which fill with class called SerialPortData.
this class contain a field in type of datetime which called dt.

I want to order (sort) nt queue per the field dt.

is there a simple way to do that?

here is what I am written so far.

```
private Queue<SerialPortData> sortQueuePerTime(Queue<SerialPortData> qsd)
{
        Queue<SerialPortData> _newQSD = new Queue<SerialPortData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < qsd.Count; i=i+2)
        {
            if(i==qsd.Count-1)
            {

                break;
            }
            int result = DateTime.Compare(qsd.ElementAt(i).dt, qsd.ElementAt(i+1).dt);
            if(result<0)
            {
                _newQSD.Enqueue(qsd.ElementAt(i));
                _newQSD.Enqueue(qsd.ElementAt(i+1));
            }
            else
            {

                _newQSD.Enqueue(qsd.ElementAt(i+1));
                _newQSD.Enqueue(qsd.ElementAt(i));
            }
        }
        return _newQSD;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947195/sorting-a-queue)

Comment: I think your code has an awful performance comparing with Harold answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting Linq do it is an option, I would test your solution against this and see if one performs better than the other.

```
//Something Like this...
using System.Linq;
private Queue<SerialPortData> sortQueuePerTime(Queue<SerialPortData> qsd)
{
    return new Queue<SerialPortData>(qsd.OrderBy(q => q.dt));
}
```